# Vim-like key remapping of colon and semicolon in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, vim, key-bindings

I'm looking to swap the colon and semi-colon keys in Sublime Text 2 (using vintage mode). Ideally, I'm aiming to recreate the following vimscript behavior:

```
cnoremap ; :
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;
```

However I've been searching the Sublime Text docs and have been unable to find the correct command to trigger the remapping of keys. Does such a command exist? What would be the most succinct way to express these commands?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to **Preferences -> Key Bindings -> User**

```
  { "keys": [";"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "command_palette", "text": ":"},
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
  },

  { "keys": [":"], "command": "set_repeat_move_to_character_motion",
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
  }
```

This will override the default values set in ./Packages/Vintage/Default.sublime-keymap. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

There probably isn't such a command. There isn't anything wrong with using those three lines you posted.

(If you don't know about it, though, you can use `:helpgrep` to search through the help docs.)

Comment: You misunderstand – above are lines from my .vimrc that I'm looking to recreate in Sublime Text 2. I'll edit my post to make it more clear.